# Require Compass plugins (Gems) in Rails 3.2.X

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sass

I'm fairly new to Rails but I use sass/compass everyday in non-Rails projects.

I want to use compass plugin gems (e.g. `compass-rgbapng`) along with `compass` in the project (`Rails 3.2.4`). I'm using `compass-rails` too with `gem 'sass-rails ~> 3.2.6'` and `gem 'sass ~> 3.2.7'`.

I added both gems to the `Gemfile` in the `:assets` group. I `bundle install`ed, etc. I use the `@import` call in my `sass` files to use the gems.

Here is what I get from the server :

> File to import not found or unreadable: rgbapng.
>   Load paths:
>
> > Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/app/assets/stylesheets/store/_base.sass)
> >      /Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/app/assets/stylesheets
> >      /Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass->0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
> >      /Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass->0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
> >      /Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/breakpoint-2.0.7/stylesheets
> >      Compass::SpriteImporter
> >      (in /Users/simonwalsh/src/quarterly/app/assets/stylesheets/store/_base.sass)

I did *not* require the gem anywhere as it is not supposed to be required. Even then, I don't even have a compass.rb or any other config files...

--- EDIT ---

I went to `compass-rails` doc to try their way of doing that. Here is what I tried :

1. I added a `compass.rb` in the `initializer` with either `require 'rgbapng'` or `config.compass.require 'rgbapng'` in it,
2. I tried the same as above in the `application.rb` file.

Still nothing works, the app refuses to comply with my `@import rgbapng` call...

Comment: Have you tried looking specifically for Compass+Rails documentation?  See if this helps: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails

Comment: Yep I'll edit the question to show you which steps I've done!